# show array in single line in debug view in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Arrays in my debug view in eclipse are shown element-by-element downwards. This makes it difficult visually if I have too many arrays since I have to keep scrolling and cannot see all of them on a single screen.

Is there a way to see the array in a single line in the Variables section of the debug view in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below snippet to print in one line.

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(theArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way (that I know of) of showing the array in a single line in the Variables View. I don't have eclipse installed in this PC but, as Kulbhushan said, you can try to execute the code

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(array);
```

in the Display View (to open it go to **Window > Show View > Display**).